# Mongoose find() slow on large documents

Tags: mongodb

This query never finishes:

```
   const stocks = await mongoose.model("stock").find().exec();
    console.log(stocks.length);
```

This query is executed in < 1 second

```
   const stocks = await mongoose.model("stock").find().select("ticker").exec();
    console.log(stocks.length);
```

I have a lot of data on each stock (10 years of stockdata).

What is mongoose doing? Some validation on each find? Some setting I can use to turn it off?

Or is the only option to use mongodb native?

**Update:**

Ok So I tried to do it mongo native instead:

```
console.log("start");
    const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
    await MongoClient.connect(connectionMongoUrl, (err, db) => {
      if (err != null) {
        console.log(err);
        return Promise.reject(err);
      }
      const dbo = db.db("tradestats");
      dbo
        .collection("stocks")
        .find({})
        .toArray(async function (err, stocks) {
          console.log(stocks.length); // never fires
```

Same problem! It never finishes. So it's not mongoose then. What can it be? Some memory settings in nodejs or something?

**Update2:**

Is it bad data model design? Wrong database? Should 10 years of stock prices be put in a separate collection and use reference instead?

Comment: can you post some sample document, and you know total count of the documents?

Comment: total nr of document is about 800. Each stock has a price sub array with about 2500 items with 4 properties each.

Comment: is there any specific reason behind selecting all records using single query? obviously this will take time to fetch all records, you really need to change the way of fetching records, use pagination skip and limit.

Comment: I'm doing some calculations on prices each day. So I get all stocks, do calculations for each one of them, save the result to db. So yes I need to fetch them all.

Comment: Why don't you perform the calculation in the aggregation query? Can you just elaborate on the proper requirement so that I can help you with? Also, adding the toArray() function, in the end, will return the array with all the documents in it, which is very costly for both storing and delivering the document, Instead, what you do is, use the mongoCursor to send the data in chunks. Or you can limit the documents as @turivishal suggested.

Answer (score 1):

> What is mongoose doing? Some validation on each find? Some setting I can use to turn it off?

In short: It does a lot different things. There a [good article about the details of find();](https://thecodebarbarian.com/how-find-works-in-mongoose)

10 years of stock data is a lot.I don't think you use the right database for your use-case. MongoDB is not design for these kind of use-cases. It is a document oriented database and you should treat it like this. I highly recommend column based databases for this kind of use-cases. Cassandra might be a good choice. Another, more complicated solution, might be Apache ORC on the hadoop file system, if you need it to scale.

You can also just try to increase the timeout settings, so that it doesn't timeout. It will not improve the performance, but at least your query will not fail. MongoDB needs to iterate over all these documents and get the desired information. Without indexes that can be a lot which leads to a poor performance. So, adding indexes might help.
Another performance improvement in case of MongoDB might be to use the [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) or [Map Reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/). To limit the memory usage.

Comment: A bit extreme to change database. What if I keep the price data in a seperate collection and make reference instead? Is this best practice if you have a subdoc-array with more than xx items?

Comment: @Joe Yes, you could do that and that could improve the performance. You can model relations in MongoDB. But it is not a relational database. You can also use LIKE queries in Cassandra, while it is isn't designed for that purpose. I would use these features carefully and keep the core design of the db in mind. MongoDB is not designed for timeseries data or column filtering. That doesn't mean MongoDB is a bad db. Just not design for these kind of use-cases.

Comment: No problems to use relations via mongoose. Done it in many projects. I find it hard to believe mongo is not suited for this. I'll with with approve and see if any more answers come in.

Comment: @Joe Fair enough. Maybe somebody else has another idea to optimize the query in your use-case to make it usable. Btw: Have you already scaled MongoDB to multiple server? Or is it just running on one node?

Comment: It's running on a separate node. It's only me using it. No other users.